# Using this SVG as map in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, mapping, svg

I have a working OpenLayers web page using standard maptiler tiles, and tons of markers as points using `lonlat`. Now I want to migrate from the maptiler tiles to a particular world map in SVG format (paths). This is how the map looks like (as JPG):

[image]

So, how to transform the GPS coordinates to the map coordinates? The very first problem is to know which projection the SVG is using (if any!). How to know that?

Comment: For static map image you'll have to use `ol.source.ImageStatic` layer source, and for this you'll need image extent (corner coordinates) and the image projection. You'll have to get both these at the source where you got the image.